# flutter createState being called on every widget in the navigation stack on every navigation

Tags: flutter

I'm reusing the same class to create several stateful widgets.  Everything is running just fine, but I noticed every one of these instances in the stack is calling createState -> initState then immediately calling dispose every time I navigate to a new page.  I'm using GetX for navigation.  This doesn't seem normal.  Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  Dumb as hell.  I had read somewhere to exclusively use Get.to(() => Page) instead of Get.to(Page).  Turns out Get.to(() => Page) rebuilds the entire widget tree including each widgets state.  Hope this helps anyone else with this problem.